# pandas: extracting dataframe using combination logic on dataframe's column contains string with exact match or only their combinations

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have a dataframe where sig column has string where it comes as single or group of string. If i want to extract only dataframe where my string matching how can I do that?

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['sig'] = ['301','302','303','405','405 409','302 301','303 301','405','560','309','301 302 303','303 304','305','305 304 303 302 301', '555','565','301 302 303 304']
df['val'] = [45,25,1,54,12,51,52,1,4,152,786,145,1,555,7595,77,89]
```

if I add string `'301 302 303'` to find the same match and where it contains combinations but
it also gives the additional rows where it contains `301 302 303 304` or like that
I tried this way

```
dtc = '301 302 303'
dtcs = dtc.split()
x = df['sig'].str.contains(dtcs[0])
for i in range (1, len(dtcs)):
    x = x | df['sig'].str.contains(dtcs[i])
    df_dtc = df[x]
    print(df_dtc)
    print('****************')
```

which gives the ouput like this

```
# output
                    sig  val
0                   301   45
1                   302   25
5               302 301   51
6               303 301   52
10          301 302 303  786
13  305 304 303 302 301  555
16      301 302 303 304   89
****************
                    sig  val
0                   301   45
1                   302   25
2                   303    1
5               302 301   51
6               303 301   52
10          301 302 303  786
11              303 304  145
13  305 304 303 302 301  555
16      301 302 303 304   89
```

**expected output**

```
output 

sig           val

301            45
302            25
303             1
302 301        51 
303 301        52
301 302 303   786
```

it means all its combination and without repetations and getting only exact or combinations of that.
as you can see it is not adding rows

```
303 304
305 304 303 302 301
301 302 303 304 etc.....
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The following is a bit ugly but does what I believe is what you are looking for...

```py
# Convert 'sig' to a set
df['sig_as_set'] = df['sig'].str.split().map(set)

# same for 'dtc'
dtc_as_set = {'301', '302', '303'}

# Locate rows of interest (where sig_of_set must be subset of dtc_as_set)
df['row_of_interest'] = df['sig_as_set'].apply(lambda sos: sos.issubset(dtcs_as_set))
```

`df.query('row_of_interest')` returns...

```
    sig         val sig_as_set      row_of_interest
0   301          45 {301}           True
1   302          25 {302}           True
2   303           1 {303}           True
5   302 301      51 {301, 302}      True
6   303 301      52 {301, 303}      True
10  301 302 303 786 {301, 303, 302} True
```

This assumes sig is non-empty.

Comment: find out the solution for myself. But thanks for your help... See my answer. Maybe you can optimize it. Will help me anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Just first `split` the string then uses `itertools.permutations` and concatenate the data frame where the string is matching.

```
dt = '301 302 303' 
import itertools
list1 = dt.split()
parent_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range (1, len(list1) + 1):
    for subset in itertools.permutations(list1, i):
        a = ' '.join(subset)
        df_dtc = df[df['sig'] == a]
        parent_df = pd.concat([parent_df,df_dtc], axis=0)
        del(df_dtc)
        
print(parent_df)
```

The expected output of this is following

```
#output

            sig  val
0           301   45
1           302   25
2           303    1
6       301 303   52
5       302 301   51
10  301 302 303  786
```